# Operators for norm for some classes of integral operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, integral-transforms

Let $T:L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a linear operator of the form: for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$
$$
T_{\kappa}(f)(x):=\int_{u\in\mathbb{R}^n} \, f(u)\kappa(u,x)du,
$$
where $\kappa:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous function and multiplication is componentwise.

Is there a class of $\kappa$ for the operator norm of $T_{\kappa}$ is known and is expressed explicitly in terms of $\kappa$?

**Edit**
The types of integral operators I am interested in are specified by the following type types of kernel functions:

1. $\kappa(u,x)=(\tilde{\kappa}(u_1-x_1),\dots,\tilde{\kappa}(u_n-x_n))$ where $\tilde{\kappa}$ is a strictly increasing continuous map from the $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0,1]$, *(Similar in spirit to what Yemon wrote)*
2. $\kappa(u,x)=K_x \,u$ where each $K_x$ is a symmetric positive-definite matrix-valued function satisfying the non-degeneracy condition
   $$
   0<m:=\inf_{x}\,|\sigma_{\min}(K_x)|\leq \sup_{x}\,|\sigma_{\max}(K_x)|=:M<\infty
   $$
3. $\kappa(u,x)=K_x \,u$ where each $K_x$ is a square matrix satisfying
   $$
   \sup_{x}\, \|K_x\|_{\ell^{\infty}}=:M^{\prime}<\infty
   $$

---

If anyone knows, and purely out of curiosity, what about examples from these classes:

- The components of $\kappa$ belongs to a Sobolev space $W^{k,\infty}$ for large $k$,
- The components of $\kappa$ are non-constant and compactly supported smooth (class-$C^{\infty}$) function.

Though, I'm asking about integral operators of types $1$, $2$, or $3$ above (only curious about the other types if anyone happens to know).

Comment: Well, can you express the operator norm of an $n$-by-$n$ matrix explicitly in terms of the matrix?

Comment: Could you narrow down your question a bit, perhaps by adding some examples of the kinds of integral operators where you would want to know the exact operator norm? Would positivity assumptions be natural in the setting you are considering?

Comment: As a thought experiment: if we define $\kappa_n(u,v) = \exp( 2\pi i n (u-v) )$ then $T$ has rank $1$ and norm $1$. But this is a very special "class of $\kappa$" so I don't know if this is what you need.

Comment: @YemonChoi I added some examples of integral kernels I am interested in; specifically, the first two types are of interest to me.  The latter is mostly from curiosity.

Comment: @YemonChoi Does the reasoning of your example hold for the class of operators in $1$?

Comment: How do you mutliply two $\mathbb{R}^n$ vectors to obtain an $R^n$ vector : component by component? Why do you integrate over $[0,1]$? Or do you really mean $n=1$?

Comment: @username Integration should be over $\mathbb{R}^n$ and multiplication is componentwise.

Comment: Type 2 and 3 do not work : they is linear in $u$, so won't be L^2 : the output is possibly undefined let alone L^2 (try in 1D).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I'm convinced; if $n=1$ as you suggest then 
$
\|K_x f\|= \sup_{x}|K_x |\|f\| \leq M \|f\|.
$
Therefore, $\|T(f)\|\leq M\|f\|$ whence $\|T\|_{op}\leq M$.